# Limesurvey add_response API without sessionkey

Tags: limesurvey

I would like to add response to a survey as an anonymous user through Remote Control API.
But LimeSurvey's all Remote control APIs required session key as an input parameter.

Is there anyway to add response as an anonymous user through Remote Control API without passing session key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,

The session key is needed to disallow anybody to set 'what they want' in your DB.

It's a session key from admin : you can create an admin and use his session key to set an answer.
You can too : make a php (or ruby, or java, or anythink you want) receiving anonymous request, add the session key and follow up to your LS administration.